# JavaScript weird issue with else if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I'm making a game of Guess the Number, and I want to test if a variable `guess` is greater than a variable `difficulty`. `difficulty` has been taken from my HTML page, and it is not comparing correctly with `guess`.

```js
//Initialize variables for player guess, guess counter and previous guesses
var guess = 0;
var guessCount = 0;
var previousGuesses = [];

function startGame() {
 
 //Calculate difficulty
 var difficulty = document.getElementById("difficulty").value;
 
 //Calculate secret number
 var secretNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * difficulty) + 1);
 
 //Repeats while player has not guessed the secret number
 while (guess != secretNumber) {
  
  //Checks for Cancel button pressed
  guess = prompt("Enter your guess: ");
  if (guess == null) {
   return;
  } 
  
  //Checks for empty string/no input
  else if (guess == "") {
   alert("Please enter a number");
  }
  
  //Checks if previously guessed
  else if (previousGuesses.includes(guess)) {
   alert("You have guessed this number before. Please try a different number.");
  }
  
  else if (guess < 1) {
   alert("Please enter a number between 1-" + difficulty);
  }
  
  //Checks if guess is higher than secretNumber
  else if (guess > secretNumber) {
   alert("Your guess is too high");
   //Increments guess counter
   guessCount++;
   //Adds the previous guess to previousGuesses
   previousGuesses.push(guess);
  } 
  
  //Checks if guess is lower than secretNumber
  else if (guess < secretNumber) {
   alert("Your guess is too low");
   //Increments guess counter
   guessCount++;
   //Adds the previous guess to previousGuesses
   previousGuesses.push(guess);
  }
  
  //Checks for correct guess
  else if (guess == secretNumber) {
   //Increments guess counter
   guessCount++;
   
   //Checks for correct grammar - guesses or guess
   if (guessCount > 1) {
    alert("Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in " + guessCount + " guesses!");
   }
   else {
    alert("Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in " + guessCount + " guess!");
   }
  }
  
 }
 //Resets variables to play again
 guess = 0;
 guessCount = 0;
 previousGuesses = [];
}
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 animation: background 10s infinite;
}

h1 {
 margin-top: 48px;
 margin-bottom: 48px;
 animation: heading 10s infinite;
}

button {
 height: 48px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Guess the Number</h1>

<button onclick="startGame()">Start the Game</button>

<h2>Difficulty</h2>

<select id="difficulty">
  <option value="10">Beginner</option>
  <option value="50">Intermediate</option>
  <option value="100">Hard</option>
</select>
```

***Read this: key info***

This code works, but I want something to happen: When the guess is greater than `difficulty`, I want to print `"Please enter a number between 1-" + difficulty`. However, when I change this code:

```js
else if (guess < 1) {
    alert("Please enter a number between 1-" + difficulty);
}
```

into this:

```js
else if (guess < 1 || guess > difficulty) {...}
```

(EDIT: the above code is to find out if the guess is greater than `difficulty`)

then what happens is that EVERY guess except `1`, `difficulty` and anything more than `difficulty` is alerted by `Please enter a number`.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Note that strings are compared lexicographically, so e.g. `"6" > "50"`, but `"4" < "50"`.

Comment: `guess = +prompt("Enter your guess: ");` bonus: you won't need to check for `null` or `''` anymore

Comment: you are getting a value which is in format of string.. convert it into parseInt

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, someone else gained access to my account. I apologise for this, it will not occur again. Please can you remove your downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing strings not numbers. Convert your strings into numbers.

```
else if (parseInt(guess) < 1 || parseInt(guess) > parseInt(difficulty))
```

Better way: Convert it directly after input and...

```
guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your guess: "));
```

...get the difficulty value as number

```
var difficulty = parseInt(document.getElementById("difficulty").value);
```

```js
//Initialize variables for player guess, guess counter and previous guesses
var guess = 0;
var guessCount = 0;
var previousGuesses = [];

function startGame() {
 
 //Calculate difficulty
 var difficulty = parseInt(document.getElementById("difficulty").value);
 
 //Calculate secret number
 var secretNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * difficulty) + 1);
 
 //Repeats while player has not guessed the secret number
 while (guess != secretNumber) {
  
  //Checks for Cancel button pressed
  guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your guess: "));
  if (guess == null) {
   return;
  } 
  
  //Checks for empty string/no input
  else if (guess == "") {
   alert("Please enter a number");
  }
  
  //Checks if previously guessed
  else if (previousGuesses.includes(guess)) {
   alert("You have guessed this number before. Please try a different number.");
  }
  
  else if (guess < 1 || guess > difficulty) {
     
   alert("Please enter a number between 1-" + difficulty);
  }
  
  //Checks if guess is higher than secretNumber
  else if (guess > secretNumber) {
   alert("Your guess is too high");
   //Increments guess counter
   guessCount++;
   //Adds the previous guess to previousGuesses
   previousGuesses.push(guess);
  } 
  
  //Checks if guess is lower than secretNumber
  else if (guess < secretNumber) {
   alert("Your guess is too low");
   //Increments guess counter
   guessCount++;
   //Adds the previous guess to previousGuesses
   previousGuesses.push(guess);
  }
  
  //Checks for correct guess
  else if (guess == secretNumber) {
   //Increments guess counter
   guessCount++;
   
   //Checks for correct grammar - guesses or guess
   if (guessCount > 1) {
    alert("Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in " + guessCount + " guesses!");
   }
   else {
    alert("Congratulations, you guessed the correct number in " + guessCount + " guess!");
   }
  }
  
 }
 //Resets variables to play again
 guess = 0;
 guessCount = 0;
 previousGuesses = [];
}
```

```html
<h1>Guess the Number</h1>

<button onclick="startGame()">Start the Game</button>

<h2>Difficulty</h2>

<select id="difficulty">
  <option value="10">Beginner</option>
  <option value="50">Intermediate</option>
  <option value="100">Hard</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why not just `guess = +prompt("Enter your guess: ");` and always work with numbers :p

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much @alexP!

Answer (score 2):

change `else if (guess < 1 || guess > parseInt(difficulty))`

to `else if (parseInt(guess) < 1 || parseInt(guess) > parseInt(difficulty))`

or change the type at the input

```
guess = parseInt(prompt("Enter your guess: "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the built-in `Number` function. See how I fixed your code below:

```
difficulty = Number(difficulty);
guess = Number(guess);
```

Try applying this after your variables are declared and it should work!

Answer (score 1):

Change to this should help:

```
else if (guess < 1 || guess > parseInt(difficulty)) {
```